# jQuery JSON object keep duplicating when onChange event

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I have 3 level of dropdown menu. Each of this menu is related to each other. The first selected menu will result in the second menu and the second menu will lead to the third menu. Please take a look at 
[my animated screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S715q.gif).

As we can **see in the console**, the output is kept doubling for each onChange event. In the HTML, the result is only one but in the console, it shows multiple records.

you guys can check out my code at https://jsfiddle.net/4v9zyb6d/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dataInfo = {
    "==Please choose==": {
      "==Please choose==": {
        "==Please choose==": {
          "data": "==Please choose=="
        }
      }
    },
    "Data A - level 1": {
      "Data A1 - level 2": {
        "Data A11 - level 3": {
          "data": "Info data A11"
        },
        "Data A12 - level 3": {
          "data": "Info data A12"
        }
      },
      "Data A2 - level 2": {
        "Data A21 - level 3": {
          "data": "Info data A21"
        }
      },
      "Data A3 - level 2": {
        "Data A31 - level 3": {
          "data": "Info data A31"
        }
      }
    },
    "Data B - level 1": {
      "Data B1 - level 2": {
        "Data B11 - level 3": {
          "data": "Info data B11"
        }
      },
      "Data B2 - level 2": {
        "Data B21 - level 3": {
          "data": "Info data B21"
        }
      }
    }
  }

  "use strict";

  var objData1, objData2, objData3;
  var data1, data2, data3;

  success(dataInfo)

  function success(dataInfo) {
    objData1 = dataInfo;
    var variable1 = $("#level1").on("change", function() {
      viewData2(objData1[this.value])
    });
    for (data1 in objData1) {
      $("<option />").val(data1).text(data1).appendTo(variable1);
    }
    variable1.change();
  }

  function viewData2(objData1) {
    objData2 = objData1;
    var variable2 = $("#level2").on("change", function() {
      viewData3(objData2[this.value])
    });
    $("#level2").empty();
    for (data2 in objData2) {
      $("<option />").val(data2).text(data2).appendTo(variable2);
    };
    variable2.change();
  }

  //start doubling
  function viewData3(objData2) {
    objData3 = objData2;
    var variable3 = $("#level3").on("change", function() {
      valueTextbox(objData3[this.value]);
    });
    $("#level3").empty();
    for (data3 in objData3) {
      $("<option />").val(data3).text(data3).appendTo(variable3);
    };
  }

  function valueTextbox(k) {
    console.log(k)
    var z = JSON.stringify(k);
    $.each(k, function() {
      $("#mydata").text(z)
    })
  }



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="level1">level1</label>
  <select id="level1"></select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="level2">level2</label>
  <select id="level2"></select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="level3">level3</label>
  <select id="level3"></select>
</div>

<div id="mydata"></div>
```

My question:

1.I can avoid the dropdown list being duplicated for each onChange request by put the empty(). Is there any similar solution for handling the object?

Comment: Thanks but it is not what I looking for.... You can see my screen recording here https://i.stack.imgur.com/S715q.gif , the console result is kind of duplicating and redundant each time the onchange event is trigger..

Comment: Actually, the problem is still there, you can see here https://i.imgur.com/uvse3uV.gifv

Comment: Sorry, wrong link. https://jsfiddle.net/9f9xzvwz/1/

Comment: yeahhhh....you are right @bassxzero and your code much cleaner.... thank you so much!!!  One more favour, after the first menu is selected, how can I put "==please choose==" at the top of the second menu.

Comment: @bassxzero, I managed to put the "==please choose==" at my second menu by adding **$("<option />").val(blank).text(blank).appendTo($("#level1"));** under the **$("#level2").empty();** .... thank you so much for your help and I really appriciate it